# How to compile NLog NLog-5.2.2?

Tags: nlog

In our product we are using Nlog 2.0 version which is quite old and now we trying to upgrade it to Version NLog-5.2.2. but facing build issues.
Can you please suggest/ share steps to follow if any ? to successfully build .

Followed steps:
Step 1: Downloaded source from https://github.com/NLog/NLog/releases/tag/v5.2.2
Step 2: Opened NLog.proj and started compiling locally but the build is failing with multiple compilation errors:

Can you please suggest/ share steps to follow if any ? to successfully build NLog.proj in locally .

Comment: See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/5295

Comment: After having forked the NLog-project, then you should open the Visual Studio Solution-file `NLog.sln` in the `src`-folder. The `NLog.proj`-file only contains scripts for building the NLog.Schema-nuget-package.

Comment: See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/5411